# Access XML parameters via PHP's SoapServer

Tags: php, soap, soapserver

I am trying to receive a SOAP packet using PHP's SoapServer object.  I have success with the basic setup of having the request handled by SoapServer, as such:

```
$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/lead'));
$server->addFunction('lead');
$server->handle();
```

which calls the appropriate function and passes in an stdObject representing the XML passed in the HTTP request.  My problem is that there is data being passed as an XML attribute which is not conveyed in the object generated by SoapServer:

```
<Lead LeadID="6">
```

How can I retrieve the value of the LeadID attribute?

Comment: Can you view this Lead node? Tried var_dumping contents?

Comment: I can.  I get a hierarchical stdClass which represents every element under the `<Lead>` element, just no attributes.

Comment: Try parsing the XML response instead?

Comment: That seems like it would defeat the purpose of using SoapServer.  If there is a more correct way of accomplishing this, I would rather it.